# Calculate Mean Squared Error for different value-ranges

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a .csv with a lot of values between -110 and -50. I want to calculate the Mean Squared Error for a range of 10 ([-110, -100], [-100, -90] etc.). The main purpose is, that in the end I can plot the values of the MSE for the different ranges and can see the behavior.
To import and read the csv I use following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('MY_Bahnhof_Bridge_DATASET.csv')


data_Measured = data['rsrp_measured'] 
data_Simulated = data['rsrp_simulated']
```

To calculate the MSE I used this function from numpy, but I don't know if it support ranges like pyplot:

```
MSE = np.square(np.subtract(data_Messung,data_Simulation)).mean()
```

Or another function I found is:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

MSE = mean_squared_error(data_Measured, data_Simulated)
```

Does anyone know a comfortable solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to understand what the data is. As I've understood, you want to calculate MSE within each bin of width 10 for differences between `rsrp_measured` and `rsrp_simulated`. You can achieve that using `groupby` with `apply` like below:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Calculate differences
data["diff"] = data.eval('rsrp_measured - rsrp_simulated')

# Get bins of width 10
data["bin"] = data["diff"] // 10

# Get MSE per bin
data.groupby("bin").apply(lambda x:
    mean_squared_error(x["rsrp_measured"], x["rsrp_simulated"]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You are right, I want to calculate MSE within each bin of width 10, but not for the differences. I want to have a plot with the range of the MSE values on the y-axis, and the range of the values of rsrp_measured on the x-axis. And for each bin of width 10 on the x-axis, the value of the MSE relating to the same range of rsrp_simulatied. So in the end I have 5 - 6 points which tell me, how big the MSE between Measurement and Simulation is depending on the bin of rsrp_measured.